# Rails bundle nokogiri

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm making a first attempt learning to work with an api and I'm trying to use the gem urban_dictionary.  My gem file looks like this

```html
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.0.beta2'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0.0.beta1'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jQuery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 4.0.0.beta2'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

gem 'urban_dictionary'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'debugger' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'

  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0.0.beta4'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end
```

Bundle is returning the following error and I'm stuck trying to figure out a solution:

```html
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
Resolving dependencies...
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "nokogiri":
  In Gemfile:
    urban_dictionary (>= 0) ruby depends on
      nokogiri (~> 1.5.2) ruby

    rails (= 4.2.0.beta2) ruby depends on
      actionpack (= 4.2.0.beta2) ruby depends on
        rails-html-sanitizer (>= 1.0.1, ~> 1.0) ruby depends on
          loofah (~> 2.0) ruby depends on
            nokogiri (1.6.3.1)
```

Thank for your time and help.

Comment: maybe try using a stable version of rails? `gem 'rails', '~> 4.1'`

Comment: you need to find versions that are compatible. otherwise bundler will not allow you to bundle successfully even-though the versions might be compatible